# Sort List of strings as numbers - found solution but don't know how to implement

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

I would like to implement http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html in my code to do some natural sorting of strings with numbers at beginning and end.  My problem, having not done much sorting is how do I implement this into my object structure.

I have a

```
    List<string[]> myStringArrays = new List<string[]>();
```

and I've added 1000's of arrays of this type:

```
    "text", "text", "1, label:3", "","","", etc ...
    "text", "text", "2, label:2", "","","", etc ...
    "text", "text", "2, label:1", "","","", etc ...
    "text", "text", "10, label:3", "","","", etc ...
```

EDIT: (label is always "label" in this example)

and I've been sorting with LINQ

```
      myStringArrays = myStringArrays.OrderBy(m => m[2]).ToList();
```

but as you've guessed, it sorts to give the alpha sort "1...", "10..." and so on.

I tried this approach:

```
      myStringArrays = myStringArrays.OrderBy(m => (m[2].Split(',')[0])).ThenBy(m => m[2].Split(':')[2]).ToList();
```

which works but fails if my 3rd string doesn't meet that specific format. This leads me (eventually) to my question - how would I implement the Alphanum.cs to solve this problem?

Comment: shouldn't that be `.ThenBy(m => m[2].Split(':')[1])` instead of `.ThenBy(m => m[2].Split(':')[2])`?

Comment: oh, sorry, forgot to mention that "label" seems to be always the same.  It's an identifier like "Experiment" ... so I'd only need to sort on the digit at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not hard to implement, it's just a matter of parsing the strings to split them up in numeric and non-numeric characters, and compare them. Here is an implementation that I threw together:

```
public class AlphaNum : IComparable<AlphaNum> {

  private List<string> _alphas;
  private List<int> _nums;

  public AlphaNum(string value) {
    _alphas = new List<string>();
    _nums = new List<int>();
    bool alpha = true;
    int ofs = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= value.Length; i++) {
      if (i == value.Length || Char.IsDigit(value[i]) == alpha) {
        string s = value.Substring(ofs, i - ofs);
        if (alpha) {
          _alphas.Add(s);
        } else {
          _nums.Add(Int32.Parse(s));
        }
        ofs = i;
        alpha = !alpha;
      }
    }
  }

  public int CompareTo(AlphaNum other) {
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
      bool e = i >= _alphas.Count;
      bool oe = i >= other._alphas.Count;
      if (e || oe) return e && oe ? 0 : e ? -1 : 1;
      int c = _alphas[i].CompareTo(other._alphas[i]);
      if (c != 0) return c;
      e = i >= _nums.Count;
      oe = i >= other._nums.Count;
      if (e || oe) return e && oe ? 0 : e ? -1 : 1;
      c = _nums[i].CompareTo(other._nums[i]);
      if (c != 0) return c;
    }
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
myStringArrays = myStringArrays.OrderBy(x => new AlphaNum(x[2])).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks - I think I need to go back to my "HeadFirst C#" and look at the implementation of sorting methods.  Tested your code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation of natural sort should get you started: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting

Comment: I think I'm getting stuck with actually using any of these. I seem to be able to sort arrays with Array.Sort but as soon as I get to order a list of arrays I end up floundering ...